# How to create overlay at the bottom of view pager for image slider in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio, android-layout-weight

I want to make layout for Image Slider, so have to create the view pager as well as have to make a overlay at the bottom of view pager.
How can I create that layout for Image Slider.
[image]

[image]

As i mentioned above image like that want to make layout in android
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Use Horizontal ListView ot Recycle View With Some Layout-manager

Comment: this may useful to you : https://github.com/crosswall/Android-Coverflow

Comment: @Nivethitha see my answer below.

Comment: use recycle view with layout orientation horizontal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a component like this before.

Basicly those codes should be enough for you. It doesn't have to be complicated realy.

These are your layout codes. I'm sure you will manage to use them in java codes according to your needs.

Here is the link for horizontalListView:
https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffAAAAAA" />

    <!--You may use here-->
    <!--HorizontalListView or-->
    <!--RecyclerView with horizontal layoutManager-->
    <!--I would use HorizontalListView it's easier-->
    <!--You may find it by searching in google-->
    <HorizontalListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="#66FFffFF" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

this is xml code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
  <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/selected"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_above="@+id/gallery_relative_layout"
          android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
          android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
          android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
 
            />
  <View
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="1dp"
          android:background="#000000"
          android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
          android:layout_above="@+id/gallery_relative_layout"
            />
 
  <RelativeLayout
          android:id="@+id/gallery_relative_layout"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="200dip"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:paddingTop="20dp">
 
    <HorizontalScrollView
          android:id="@+id/hor_scroll_view"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               >
      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/gallery"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/im1"
            android:onClick="biggerView"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/im2"
            android:onClick="biggerView"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/im3"
            android:onClick="biggerView"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/im4"
            android:onClick="biggerView"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/im5"
                android:onClick="biggerView"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/im6"
                android:onClick="biggerView"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/im7"
                android:onClick="biggerView"/>
      </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
  </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is MainActivity.java code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 
    ImageView im;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
 
 
    public void biggerView(View v)
    {
       im=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.selected);
 
       switch (v.getId())
       {
           case R.id.image1: im.setImageResource(R.drawable.im1);
                             break;
           case R.id.image2: im.setImageResource(R.drawable.im2);
                             break;
           case R.id.image3: im.setImageResource(R.drawable.im3);
                             break;
           case R.id.image4: im.setImageResource(R.drawable.im4);
                             break;
           case R.id.image5: im.setImageResource(R.drawable.im5);
                             break;
           case R.id.image6: im.setImageResource(R.drawable.im6);
                             break;
           case R.id.image7: im.setImageResource(R.drawable.im7);
                             break;
       }
    }
 
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

here is output :

[image]

When you click any image it display as follow.

[image]

#### NOTE : Here I have used my Image used your Image and see the result.

Comment: Its static layout ,i want make dynamic one becoz have to creat view pager  must the get images from json. At the bottom i want to creat overlay of dynamic imageview.

Comment: see above my image,if i click one image that will move to another activity show image slider i can move four of five image then at bottom want to create overlay of displaying corresponding images

Answer (score 0):

You can use Recycler View at Bottom. and add a LinearLayoutManager with Horizontal scrolling. add a a single item image view in your adapter. It will definitely help you :)

Comment: I can use horizontal view at bottom